# VBS: Terminate multiple running applications

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am trying to close multiple applications at the same time using the following VBS script, but am getting the error `0x80041017` on the `For Each` loop line. It works fine with just one application but I added another to terminate

```
strComputer = "."
strProcessToKill1 = "Acrobat.exe" 
strProcessToKill2 = "iexplore.exe" 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
                & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
                ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & strProcessToKill1 & "' or '" & strProcessToKill2 & "'")


count = 0
For Each objProcess in colProcess
                objProcess.Terminate()
                count = count + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your WMI query is invalid, which is causing the loop to fail.  You need to specify the column (Name) for the second half of the WHERE clause.  I would also remove the brackets for the `objProcess.Terminate` call as well.

```
strComputer = "."
strProcessToKill1 = "Acrobat.exe" 
strProcessToKill2 = "iexplore.exe" 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
                & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
                ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & strProcessToKill1 & "' OR Name = '" & strProcessToKill2 & "'")


count = 0
For Each objProcess in colProcess
                objProcess.Terminate
                count = count + 1
Next
```